# Collisional quenching in fluorescence

Tags: optics, fluorescence

I am studying collisional quenching phenomenon in fluorescent measuring and I am focusing on Stern - Volmer relationship.

[image]

I can't understand why the ratio of the intensities of fluorescence is equal to quantum yields' one (and so of time-fluorescence), and there is no exponential relationship according to Lambert-Beer equation.